# Problems about angle bisectors of a trapezium

Tags: geometry

There is this geometry problem that I came across but need these conclusions in order to proceed. I really appreciate any helps.

Let $ABCD$ be a trapezium with $AB$ and $DC$ parallel. The angle bisectors of $\angle A$ and $\angle D$ intersect at $E$, and the angle bisectors of $B$ and $C$ intersect at $F$.

I am trying to divide into cases what will happen if $E$ and $F$ overlap.

If $E$ and $F$ overlap, then is it true that $AD+BC=AB+DC$? If yes, why?

If $E$ and $F$ do not overlap, then is it true that $EF$ parallel to both $AB$ and $DC$?

Are there any such theorems or propositions? I really appreciate any helps. 
Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since FB and FC are angle bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ respectively, a semi-inscribed circle can be drawn with center at F such that FP, FQ and FR are its radius r. Refer to the first figure below.

[image]

First of all, we need to show that [[PFR is in fact a straight line and hence the diameter of the circle.]

Suppose it is not but PF (produced to cut DC at S) is. By alternate angles between parallel lines $\angle PSR$ is also a right angle. In this case, we have a triangle with two of its angles being right angle. This contradicts our assumption. Thus, [[PFR is in fact a straight line.] And it is not difficult to see that it is also a diameter of the circle.]

Similarly, another circle GHK can be drawn with center at E such that EG, EH and EK are its radius.
HEK is a straight line and in fact in the diameter of the circle GHK. See the second figure.

[image]

Note that PS(or PR) and HK are perpendicular distances between the parallel lines AB and DC. Thus, PS = HK. Therefore, E and F are both at a distance r from AB. Hence, EF//AB.

In the case E coincides with F, we have just one circle. The said sum can be obtained by applying tangent properties.